# zsh: parse error near `\n' for API Key while following the MongoDB Realm Tracker Tutorial Backend

Tags: api, realm, zsh

I'm following the MONGODB REALM Task Tracker Tutorial Backend. I've added an API Key to my Project and Logged into the Realm CLI. I've read through other questions and tried the suggestions to no avail. Specifically, I've used single quotes ' and separately double quotes " around the <>. In addition, I've removed the <>.

From the tutorial: Use the following command in your terminal to authenticate with the Realm CLI:

realm-cli login --api-key  --private-api-key

In my terminal this produces the following:
MacBook-Pro ~ % realm-cli login --api-key  --private-api-key 
zsh: parse error near `\n'
MacBook-Pro ~ % realm-cli login --api-key '' --private-api-key ''
realm: invalid API key
MacBook-Pro ~ % 'realm-cli login --api-key  --private-api-key '
zsh: command not found: realm-cli login --api-key  --private-api-key 
MacBook-Pro ~ % realm-cli login '--api-key  --private-api-key '
flag provided but not defined: -api-key  --private-api-key 
MacBook-Pro ~ % realm-cli login '--api-key 'public API key' --private-api-key 'private API key'

Does anyone have any idea what I could try next?

Comment: when you post a question please include your code and error stack trace in the code block.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  Everything in the <> and including the <> needed to be replaced by the actual public and private keys.